# .shift() apparently no longer exists

Tags: javascript, function, bit-shift

https://jsfiddle.net/a/2L4t9saq/217/ is my fiddle

most of the code you can ignore, here is the function:

```
var modGrid = function(code){
    var arr = code
  console.log(arr)
    for(var n=1;n<gridx+1;n++){
        for(var i = 1; i<gridy+1; i++){
        var garbledMess = "[x="+i+"][y="+n+"]"

      var idea = arr[0]
      arr.shift()
      $(garbledMess).css("background-color",idea)
    }
    }
}
```

the syntax error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: arr.shift is not a function

at modGrid ((index):44)

at window.onload ((index):81)
```

since the modGrid function takes in an array (in the case of my code an array of 4 elements) the .shift() function should be removing the first option in the array, it worked before i added some more code, but now it is apparently not a function

many thanks

Comment: So what's that `console.log(arr)` output for starters…?

Comment: this was meant to test to see if for some reason my input was not an array, also i believe i have stated the desired behaviour, which is the function working like normal

Comment: Yes, it is to test what value `arr` is. **So what is it?**

Comment: its normally the exact array that i put into it

Comment: So what exactly does the console output right before it outputs that error?

Comment: @user10049090 It would be an array if you actually passed an array. But as you pass a string, it is a string. Try `typeof arr`.

Comment: the questions already answered, but if i input rgba(1,1,1,1.0),2,3 it'd output rgba(1,1,1,1.0),2,3 . i'd also much appreciate if you took the post off hold, a user has already answered it and it'd be a shame if a future person has this problem and is unable to see the post

Comment: @str ye i know, i read quentins reply, just a silly mistake, its all fixed up and working, but my array is still broken and i'll be asking a question on that next

Comment: try instead of `function(code){` to have `function(...code){`, which will convert all your args in a single array

Comment: The question is not self-contained enough to be answerable (without looking at the external fiddle), so it's not of much use to future visitors.

Comment: ok, i get that, but still i think i fit the criteria, i present code, present what i want it to do (in reason), someone came along, realised this from having an iq higher than 2 and answered my question with a reasonable answer, i do not understand what i did wrong, maybe i just dont understand the "intricacy's" of writing questions with so many context clues its a challenge to not understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since the modGrid function takes in an array

It is designed to take an array, but that isn't what you are passing it.

You are passing it a string, another string, a number and another number.

> ```
> modGrid('rgba(255,0,0,1)','rgba(0,255,0,1)',2,1);
> ```